# Am I handling correctly multiple projects with a common code base?

Tags: react-native

I am creating several mobile applications in react-native that share common components. I have difficulties handling the dependencies. Here is what I do, which is tedious, is there a better way?

- A repository "common-modules" has shared components
- Several repositories include the common one as a dependency like this:

#### Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "common-components": "file:../common-components"
},
```

I use it like that in the different apps:

```
import XXX from 'common-components/src/...'
```

Now this is great because all other dependencies are in "common-components", but as soon as one of them has native code, I am forced to link the library again in each app.

For instance, if I use "react-native-image-picker", I have to install it again in each application and link it in XCode, edit build.gradle etc. etc.

- It takes forever
- Are my linked dependencies bundled twice?
- I fear the day when I must change/upgrade one of them...

Is there a better way?

Comment: "I have to install it again in each application and link it in XCode, edit build.gradle etc. etc.". I afraid we have to do it for each for project.

Comment: In the end I noticed that it was far less painful to work with a duplicated code base than to try and factor it into common modules.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of projects that share code being managed in a monorepo. That may help managing shared code but won't solve the problem of linking native modules N times for N apps.

However, there is `react-native link` that should automate the process, and ease linking the native modules a lot. Note there is no need to re-link if you just upgrade a native dependency.

Alternatively, I think it should be possible to wrap multiple native modules into one. If you take a look at [MainReactPackage.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/shell/MainReactPackage.java) in RN repo, it wraps several native modules. I imagine similar mechanism can be employed on iOS, with static libraries. Obviously, this means that it won't be easy to selectively include some modules and others not.

Comment: Note: `react-native link` works for Android but in most cases you need to link through XCode for iOS (that sucks).

Comment: @JulienD I have encountered issues with ios too, namely together with cocoapods. If that is your case too, possible workaround is here https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/pull/487/files

Answer (score 0):

Like you said yourself it is easier to work with a duplicated codebase. To deal with that you can create your own package manager for your shared components. Make a script for each component which will add it's dependencies to package.json and configure gradle and XCode. Add a simple GUI to include your components with a single click.

This may seem like a lot of work upfront, but:
- you will keep full control
- once you have a script to install a component you will save time each time you use it on a new app
- in the case of updates you can create a script to handle that as well